# Can't able to get mobile number from user table wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sms-gateway

I am implementing the sms gateway plugin is called as a wp-sms. When new user signup or register the admin will get the notification and user information. Its working fine. But i can't able to get the user phone number there.

I used the nicename as a mobilenumber it stored the database correctly when i get the information for sms notification it displays the username. Can anyone tell me why it happens like that.

```
/**
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function new_user( $user_id ) {

        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );


        $template_vars = array(
            '%user_login%'    => $user->user_login,
            '%user_email%'    => $user->user_email,                
             '%user_mobile%'    => $user->user_nicename,
            '%date_register%' => $this->date,
        );
```

When i call the %user_mobile% it displays the user_login value. But in database it stores the mobile number. can anyone help me regarding this.

I used usermeta code like this but it returns empty value:

```
/**
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function new_user( $user_id ) {

        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

                 $mobile = get_user_meta( $user_id, billing_phone, true );

        $template_vars = array(
            '%user_login%'    => $user->user_login,
            '%user_email%'    => $user->user_email,                
            '%user_mobile%'    =>$mobile,
            '%date_register%' => $this->date,
        );
```

My Full Code:

```
<?php

/**
 * WP SMS notifications class
 *
 * @category   class
 * @package    WP_SMS
 * @version    1.0
 */
class WP_SMS_Notifications {

    public $sms;
    public $date;
    public $options;

    /**
     * Wordpress Database
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * Wordpress Table prefix
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $tb_prefix;

    /**
     * WP_SMS_Notifications constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        global $wpsms_option, $sms, $wp_version, $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $this->sms       = $sms;
        $this->date      = WP_SMS_CURRENT_DATE;
        $this->options   = $wpsms_option;
        $this->db        = $wpdb;
        $this->tb_prefix = $table_prefix;

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_publish_new_post'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'notification_meta_box' ) );
            add_action( 'publish_post', array( $this, 'new_post' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        // Wordpress new version
        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_publish_new_wpversion'] ) ) {
            $update = get_site_transient( 'update_core' );
            $update = $update->updates;

            if ( isset( $update[1] ) ) {
                if ( $update[1]->current > $wp_version and $this->sms->GetCredit() ) {
                    if ( get_option( 'wp_last_send_notification' ) == false ) {
                        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
                        $this->sms->msg = sprintf( __( 'WordPress %s is available! Please update now', 'wp-sms' ), $update[1]->current );
                        $this->sms->SendSMS();

                        update_option( 'wp_last_send_notification', true );
                    }
                } else {
                    update_option( 'wp_last_send_notification', false );
                }
            }

        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_register_new_user'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'new_user' ), 10, 1 );
        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_new_comment'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', array( $this, 'new_comment' ), 99, 2 );
        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_user_login'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'login_user' ), 99, 2 );
        }
    }

    public function notification_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'subscribe-meta-box', __( 'SMS', 'wp-sms' ), array(
            $this,
            'notification_meta_box_handler'
        ), 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
    }

    /**
     * @param $post
     */
    public function notification_meta_box_handler( $post ) {
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $get_group_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_prefix}sms_subscribes_group`" );
        $username_active  = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}sms_subscribes WHERE status = '1'" );
        include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/templates/wp-sms-meta-box.php";
    }

    /**
     * @param $ID
     * @param $post
     *
     * @return null
     * @internal param $post_id
     */
    public function new_post( $ID, $post ) {
        if ( $_REQUEST['wps_send_subscribe'] == 'yes' ) {
            if ( $_REQUEST['wps_subscribe_group'] == 'all' ) {
                $this->sms->to = $this->db->get_col( "SELECT mobile FROM {$this->tb_prefix}sms_subscribes" );
            } else {
                $this->sms->to = $this->db->get_col( "SELECT mobile FROM {$this->tb_prefix}sms_subscribes WHERE group_ID = '{$_REQUEST['wps_subscribe_group']}'" );
            }

            $template_vars = array(
                '%post_title%'   => get_the_title( $ID ),
                '%post_content%' => wp_trim_words( $post->post_content, 10 ),
                '%post_url%'     => wp_get_shortlink( $ID ),
                '%post_date%'    => get_post_time( 'Y-m-d', true, $ID, true ),
            );

            $message = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $_REQUEST['wpsms_text_template'] );

            $this->sms->msg = $message;
            $this->sms->SendSMS();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function new_user( $user_id ) {

        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

                 $mobile = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );

        $template_vars = array(
            '%user_login%'    => $user->user_login,
            '%user_email%'    => $user->user_email,                
                        '%user_mobile%'    =>$mobile
            '%date_register%' => $this->date,
        );

        // Send SMS to admin
        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_register_new_user_admin_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();

        // Send SMS to user register
        if ( isset( $user->mobile ) ) {
            $this->sms->to  = array( $user->mobile );
            $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_register_new_user_template'] );
            $this->sms->msg = $message;
            $this->sms->SendSMS();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $comment_id
     * @param $comment_object
     */
    public function new_comment( $comment_id, $comment_object ) {

        if ( $comment_object->comment_type == 'order_note' ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $comment_object->comment_type == 'edd_payment_note' ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
        $template_vars  = array(
            '%comment_author%'       => $comment_object->comment_author,
            '%comment_author_email%' => $comment_object->comment_author_email,
            '%comment_author_url%'   => $comment_object->comment_author_url,
            '%comment_author_IP%'    => $comment_object->comment_author_IP,
            '%comment_date%'         => $comment_object->comment_date,
            '%comment_content%'      => $comment_object->comment_content
        );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_new_comment_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();
    }

    /**
     * @param $username_login
     * @param $username
     */
    public function login_user( $username_login, $username ) {
        $this->sms->to = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );

        $template_vars  = array(
            '%username_login%' => $username->user_login,
            '%display_name%'   => $username->display_name
        );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_user_login_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();
    }

}

new WP_SMS_Notifications();
```

Comment: why are you fighting with wordpress? just create a new usermeta field "phone" and you wont fight with wordpress default functions

Comment: I tried that also it returns the empty value...

Comment: Don't use the `user_nicename` field for a phone number. Use a custom field for the phone number. If you've already tried that, and it didn't work, show us the code that didn't work.

Comment: how you store in user_meta value and how you get it?

Comment: please check the updated post!

Comment: get_user_meta() function but it returns empty value.

Comment: try to use `$mobile = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );`

Comment: do you have value in `billing_phone`?

Comment: are you using woocommerce?

Comment: Yes,The billing phone stored in database through registration form

Comment: i did'nt use woocommerce

Comment: when i use this code $mobile = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true ); it displays the text 'array'

Comment: print this value `$mobile ` and check

Comment: what you are getting if you print?

Comment: can't able to print the value because this is plugin file i am editing.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170074/discussion-between-m-lak-and-george).

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * WP SMS notifications class
 *
 * @category   class
 * @package    WP_SMS
 * @version    1.0
 */
class WP_SMS_Notifications {

    public $sms;
    public $date;
    public $options;

    /**
     * Wordpress Database
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * Wordpress Table prefix
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $tb_prefix;

    /**
     * WP_SMS_Notifications constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        global $wpsms_option, $sms, $wp_version, $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $this->sms       = $sms;
        $this->date      = WP_SMS_CURRENT_DATE;
        $this->options   = $wpsms_option;
        $this->db        = $wpdb;
        $this->tb_prefix = $table_prefix;

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_publish_new_post'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'notification_meta_box' ) );
            add_action( 'publish_post', array( $this, 'new_post' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        // Wordpress new version
        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_publish_new_wpversion'] ) ) {
            $update = get_site_transient( 'update_core' );
            $update = $update->updates;

            if ( isset( $update[1] ) ) {
                if ( $update[1]->current > $wp_version and $this->sms->GetCredit() ) {
                    if ( get_option( 'wp_last_send_notification' ) == false ) {
                        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
                        $this->sms->msg = sprintf( __( 'WordPress %s is available! Please update now', 'wp-sms' ), $update[1]->current );
                        $this->sms->SendSMS();

                        update_option( 'wp_last_send_notification', true );
                    }
                } else {
                    update_option( 'wp_last_send_notification', false );
                }
            }

        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_register_new_user'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'new_user' ), 10, 1 );
        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_new_comment'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', array( $this, 'new_comment' ), 99, 2 );
        }

        if ( isset( $this->options['notif_user_login'] ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'login_user' ), 99, 2 );
        }
        add_action( 'user_register', array(this,'myplugin_registration_save'), 10, 1 );
    }

    public function notification_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'subscribe-meta-box', __( 'SMS', 'wp-sms' ), array(
            $this,
            'notification_meta_box_handler'
        ), 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
    }

    /**
     * @param $post
     */
    public function notification_meta_box_handler( $post ) {
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $get_group_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_prefix}sms_subscribes_group`" );
        $username_active  = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}sms_subscribes WHERE status = '1'" );
        include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/templates/wp-sms-meta-box.php";
    }

    /**
     * @param $ID
     * @param $post
     *
     * @return null
     * @internal param $post_id
     */
    public function new_post( $ID, $post ) {
        if ( $_REQUEST['wps_send_subscribe'] == 'yes' ) {
            if ( $_REQUEST['wps_subscribe_group'] == 'all' ) {
                $this->sms->to = $this->db->get_col( "SELECT mobile FROM {$this->tb_prefix}sms_subscribes" );
            } else {
                $this->sms->to = $this->db->get_col( "SELECT mobile FROM {$this->tb_prefix}sms_subscribes WHERE group_ID = '{$_REQUEST['wps_subscribe_group']}'" );
            }

            $template_vars = array(
                '%post_title%'   => get_the_title( $ID ),
                '%post_content%' => wp_trim_words( $post->post_content, 10 ),
                '%post_url%'     => wp_get_shortlink( $ID ),
                '%post_date%'    => get_post_time( 'Y-m-d', true, $ID, true ),
            );

            $message = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $_REQUEST['wpsms_text_template'] );

            $this->sms->msg = $message;
            $this->sms->SendSMS();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function new_user( $user_id ) {

        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

         $mobile = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );

        $template_vars = array(
            '%user_login%'    => $user->user_login,
            '%user_email%'    => $user->user_email,                
            '%user_mobile%'    =>$mobile,
            '%date_register%' => $this->date,
        );

        // Send SMS to admin
        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_register_new_user_admin_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();

        // Send SMS to user register
        if ( isset( $user->mobile ) ) {
            $this->sms->to  = array( $user->mobile );
            $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_register_new_user_template'] );
            $this->sms->msg = $message;
            $this->sms->SendSMS();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $comment_id
     * @param $comment_object
     */
    public function new_comment( $comment_id, $comment_object ) {

        if ( $comment_object->comment_type == 'order_note' ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $comment_object->comment_type == 'edd_payment_note' ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->sms->to  = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );
        $template_vars  = array(
            '%comment_author%'       => $comment_object->comment_author,
            '%comment_author_email%' => $comment_object->comment_author_email,
            '%comment_author_url%'   => $comment_object->comment_author_url,
            '%comment_author_IP%'    => $comment_object->comment_author_IP,
            '%comment_date%'         => $comment_object->comment_date,
            '%comment_content%'      => $comment_object->comment_content
        );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_new_comment_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();
    }

    /**
     * @param $username_login
     * @param $username
     */
    public function login_user( $username_login, $username ) {
        $this->sms->to = array( $this->options['admin_mobile_number'] );

        $template_vars  = array(
            '%username_login%' => $username->user_login,
            '%display_name%'   => $username->display_name
        );
        $message        = str_replace( array_keys( $template_vars ), array_values( $template_vars ), $this->options['notif_user_login_template'] );
        $this->sms->msg = $message;
        $this->sms->SendSMS();
    }



  public function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) )
          update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $_POST['billing_phone']);

  }


}

new WP_SMS_Notifications();
```